# Computing A Multivariable Limit: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, limits

Please help me in computing the following limit.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}.$$
This will be my first attempt in computing a limit involving 2 variables.
Is this a part of multivariable calculus as it contains more than one variable?
How can I interpret this geometrically?

Thank You

Comment: Limit does not exists, if you consider two paths of approach $y=0$ and $x=\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Try converting to polar coordinates.

Comment: Would you be able to calculate the limit if you assume that $y=x^2$? Would you be able to do the same if you assume $y=x$? If these limits are different, it means that you can obtain different values if you approach $(0,0)$ along different curves and, consequently, the limit in two variables does not exist.

Comment: In general, to show that the limit does not exist at a point, you may use "Two Path Test" which @sos440 used above.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174190/prove-that-lim-limits-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2-y4-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason we teach this particular problem is to show that directional limits along straight lines are not enough. Along a straight line $y=mx,$ with $m \neq 0,$ we have
$$ f(x,mx) = \frac{2 x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2} = \frac{2 m x^3 }{x^4 + m^2 x^2} = \frac{2 m x }{x^2 + m^2}  $$ from which
$$ |f(x,mx) | = \left| \frac{2 m  }{x^2 + m^2} \right| \cdot |x| \leq \left| \frac{2 m  }{ m^2} \right| \cdot |x| = \left| \frac{2   }{ m} \right| \cdot |x|. $$ 
Also, if we take either a vertical line $x=0$ or a horizontal line $y=0$ we get 0.

So, approaching the origin along any **straight line** gives an evident limit of 0.  In one variable, that would be enough, but in at least two variables, that is not sufficient to show that there is a limit, just approach the origin along a parabola $y = m x^2$ instead, as in Davide's answer.

Answer (score 10):

Put $f(x,y):=\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$. Fix a real number $m$. Then for $x\neq 0$
$$f(x,mx^2)=\frac{2x^2mx^2}{x^4+m^2x^4}=\frac{2m}{1+m^2},$$
so if there was a limit, it would be $\frac{2m}{1+m^2}$. These one depends on $m$, which is absurd since the limit would be unique.

Answer (score 3):

As you have pointed out: Putting $(x,y) = (t,t^2)$ will give you:

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2t^4}{2t^4} = \lim_{t\to 0}1 = 1$$

Using the path $(x,y) = (t,0)$ gives

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{ 2t^2 \cdot 0 }{t^4} = \lim_{t\to 0} 0 = 0$$

Since you got a different value in each case, the original limit cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to consider the change of variables, $x^2=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$ then $\frac{2x^2y}{x^4+y^2}=\frac{2r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta}{r^2}=2\cos \theta \sin \theta$ which depends on $\theta$ and hence the limit doesn't exist since it's not unique.

Answer (score 1):

A friend teaching an elementary course recalled having *seen an example of a two variable limit where the approach along any line lead to the same value, but approach along a parabola failed* and asked me what it was. Here's one way of reverse engineering this, thinking in terms of something like homogeneous coordinates.

---

Students at this point have seen the "new type of discontinuity" (that did not exist in single variable calculus) of the function
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}.
$$
Here approaching the origin radially from different directions leads to distinct values, typically found by converting to polar coordinates. With homogeneous coordinates we can make the crucial observation that $f$ really is a function of the variable $t=y/x$. Namely, if $x\neq0$ then
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{xy/x^2}{(x^2+y^2)/x^2}=\frac{y/x}{1+(y/x)^2}=\frac{t}{1+t^2}.
$$
From this the claim is obvious because the variable $t$ takes a constant value on any ray emanating from the origin, but varies wildly, because near the origin $t$ can take any value we choose.

---

How to modify this to meet the present needs? If we want the value to be a constant along a parabola of the form $y=ax^2$ a natural idea is to write everything in terms of, not the ratio $t$, but the ratio $u=y/x^2$. Any function $g(u)$ will then have different value $g(a)$ on parabolas $y=ax^2$ with different choices of $a$. But, we also have the secondary requirement of having the same limit along any line through the origin, i.e. one with constant $t=y/x$. Let's see. We have $u=t/x$, and we are approaching the origin radially. If $t\neq0$ then $x\to0$ and $u\to\pm\infty$ according to the signs of $t$ and $x$. Also, along the line defined by $t=0$ (= the $x$-axis) we have $u=0$.

> The conclusion is that if we have a function $g(u)$ such that
>   $$g(0)=\lim_{u\to\pm\infty}g(u),$$
>   then we are in business.

All that remains is to observe that we can reuse the function $f(t)=t/(1+t^2)$ from above, and end up with
$$
g(x,y)=g(u)=\frac{u}{1+u^2}=\frac{y/x^2}{1+y^2/x^4}=\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}.
$$

Comment: Leaving it as an exercise to construct a function such that the limit along any ray or a parabola $y=ax^2$ is zero, but the limit along the curve $y=x^3$ is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y):=\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$.
Let $g(x,y):=\frac{1}{2}f(x,y)$.
Let $h(x,y):=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$.

> Lemma 1:
> $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

> Proof of Lemma 1:
> Assume that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ exists.
> If $x>0$ and $y>0$, then $h(x,y)>0$.
> If $x<0$ and $y>0$, then $h(x,y)<0$.
> So, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ must be $0$.
> If $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, then $h(x,y)=h(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\cos\theta\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta).$
> $\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)$ is not equal to $0$ for some $\theta$.
> So, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ is not $0$.
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

If $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists, then $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)$ exists.
So, if $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)$ doesn't exist, then $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ doesn't exist.
We prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

Assume that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)$ exist.
If $x\neq 0$ and $y>0$, then $g(x,y)>0$.
If $x\neq 0$ and $y<0$, then $g(x,y)<0$.
So, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)$ must be $0$.
Let $\varepsilon$ be any positive real number.
Then there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $$0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\implies |g(x,y)|<\varepsilon.$$
Let $\delta^{'}:=\min(\frac{\delta^2}{2},1)$.
Let $(x,y)$ be an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta^{'}$.

1. We consider the case in which $x\geq 0$.
   $x\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta^{'}.$
   $|y|\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta^{'}.$
   $0<\sqrt{\sqrt{x}^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x+y^2}<\sqrt{\delta^{'}+(\delta^{'})^2}\leq\sqrt{2\delta^{'}}\leq\sqrt{2\frac{\delta^2}{2}}=\delta.$
   So, $|h(x,y)|=|g(\sqrt{x},y)|<\varepsilon.$
2. We consider the case in which $x\leq 0$.
   $-x\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta^{'}.$
   $|y|\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta^{'}.$
   $0<\sqrt{\sqrt{-x}^2+y^2}=\sqrt{-x+y^2}<\sqrt{\delta^{'}+(\delta^{'})^2}\leq\sqrt{2\delta^{'}}\leq\sqrt{2\frac{\delta^2}{2}}=\delta.$
   So, $|h(x,y)|=|-h(-x,y)|=|-g(\sqrt{-x},y)|=|g(\sqrt{-x},y)|<\varepsilon.$

So, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)=0.$
By Lemma 1, this is a contradiction.

So, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)$ doesn't exist.