# Prove that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \left( {\frac{{{x^2}y - x{z^2}}}{{yz - {z^2}}}} \right)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove that:
For all $\epsilon>0$ exist $\delta>0$ which depends on $\epsilon$, such that:

$$\left| {\frac{{2{x^2}y - x{z^2}}}{{yz - {z^2}}}}-0 \right|<\epsilon$$ ever that 
$$0 < \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2}}  < \delta $$

I find it very difficult to find $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. 
Any suggestions to prove this?

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \left( {\frac{{2{x^2}y - x{z^2}}}{{yz - {z^2}}}} \right)=0$$

thanks.

Comment: What is $\delta$ and $\epsilon$? And where is your actual question: In the title or in the body?

Comment: Very hard to prove something that is false.  So it is not surprising that you cannot find appropriate $\delta$: there isn't one.

Comment: your questions do not match . Please check once .

Comment: already clarified the question

Comment: Clarify the title! Is there a 2 missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider sequences
$$
\begin{align}
(x_n,y_n,z_n)&=(n^{-1/2},2n^{-1},n^{-1})\\
(x_n,y_n,z_n)&=(0,2n^{-1},n^{-1})
\end{align}
$$
then you get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2x_n^2 y_n-x_nz_n^2}{y_n z_n-z_n^2}&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(4-n^{-1/2})=4\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2x_n^2 y_n-x_nz_n^2}{y_n z_n-z_n^2}&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}0=0
\end{align}
$$
Thus we conclude that the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{2x^2 y-x z^2}{y z-z^2}
$$
doesn't exist.

P.S.
I used approach from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174198/19538) answer.

Comment: Norbert its generally easy to show that the limit doesn't exist compared to  it exists. Is there a way to show that limit exists for multivariable case ?

Comment: In general it is hard to show that limit does exist. But in most cases you had to make some tricky estimations and use standard inequalities

Comment: @mathsalomon You are welcome!

Comment: @Theorem: In 2D, we can take $r_\alpha(t)=(t,\alpha t)$ and put it into your function to find path wise limit of $f$ when $t$ tends to $0$. After simplifying the original function, if the limit of last expression approaches to zero then probably your original function has limit $0$ at $(0,0)$. Now, we have to use $\epsilon, \delta$ to prove your limit.

Comment: @Norbert . Thanks Norbert. But, with this sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n)=(n^{-1/2},2n^{-1},n^{-1})$, I get also the limit zero. I always get zero for all path (or trayectory) I have tried. I'm pretty sure that this limit is zero.

Comment: Then you are making a mistake somwhere. After substitution you must get $4-n^{-1/2}$. And its limits is $0$ when $n\to\infty$

Comment: @Norbert. And, what is the secuence for $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \left( {\frac{{2{x^2}y - x{z^2}}}{{y^2 - xz}}} \right)$$?

Comment: Ok I'll write in more detail

Comment: @norbert. Thanks