# Find $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{ x^2 + y^4} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am doing some exercises for my Calculus 3 exam and I get stuck in this exercise:
(I need to find the limit or say that it does not exist)

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{ x^2 + y^4} $$

I tried to change it polar coordinates (so that I have only one variable) but it is messy and I dont understand it...

Can someone explain me how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174190/prove-that-lim-limits-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2-y4-0?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Approach $(0, 0)$ along $(t, t)$ as $t \to 0$ to get:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^3}{t^2 + t^4} = 0
$$

Approach $(0, 0)$ along $(t, \sqrt{t})$ as $t \to 0$ to get:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{t^2 + t^2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Thus, the limit doesn't exist.

---

In general, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316806/4583) is a good resource on how to handle such problems. The technique I've used here is to find two paths that approach $(0, 0)$ but each gives a different limit.

Comment: +1 Nice reference. For some illustrations, please see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21544/finding-limits-in-several-variables.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for sharing. Pretty plots over there. :)

Comment: @AymanHourieh many many thanks!! I was just doing it with polar coordinates. And also, my profesor just do some simple exercises... :/ but many thanks!

Comment: @Edwardo Happy to help!

Comment: @AymanHourieh I was wondering, what happens if the numerator is x^2*y^2 ?? (This was the original exercise... It was a typo sorry) If I use the same method I have that L = 0 in both... now what?

Comment: @Edwardo In that case, the limit exists. It's too late to change the question and answer here. Please start a new question and I or someone else will help.

Comment: Idea of the solution: $$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4} \le \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2} = y^2 \to 0$$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Do you want to use the sandwich theorem? (it is squeeze the rigth name?) How I can find a function  that is the lower bound effectively here??

Comment: @Edwardo Squeeze theorem, yes. The lower bound is clearly $0$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I think that I find it!

Comment: @AymanHourieh oh ok, I used then function (x^2*y^2)/(x^4 + y^4) and then I used polar coordinates on that and it tends to 0. Nevertheless, 0 is obvious. THANKS!!!!

Comment: @Edwardo Great! You're welcome.