# Limits for multivariate functions $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can anyone help me solve this question

Does the limit exists?

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$$

I tried using polar coordinates to solve this problem but I got $\frac{0}{0}$ which is an undefined number so I conclude that the limit does not exists. Also I tried to sub $y=mx$ to to test for disco unity but I keep getting $0$. I even tried $y=mx^2$ but I still get $0$. Can I use polar coords to test whether the limit exists or not?

Comment: Older question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174190/prove-that-lim-limits-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2-y4-0