# Showing a function is discontinuous by taking a limit...

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For the function,

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
 \hfill 0 \hfill &,\mbox{ if }  x = y = 0 \\
 \hfill \frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4}+y^{2}} \hfill &, \mbox{ otherwise}  
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

Show it is discontinuous at $x=y=0$ by taking the limit $x \to 0$ along the line $y = {x^2}$. I don't even know what this means, I have a really unclear professor who mumbles through things half the time. Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT:

What about the function, $$g(x,y) = \left\{ \matrix{
  0,x = y = 0 \hfill \cr 
  {{{x^2}y} \over {{x^4} + {y^2} + 1}},otherwise \hfill \cr}  \right\}$$

How do I know whether it's continuous at x=y=0 because I can't make a substitution like before...

Comment: Hint: If $y = x^2,\ \ f(x,y) = f(x, x^2) = g(x) = \dots $

Comment: See also: [Computing A Multivariable Limit: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93886) or [Prove that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{x{y^2}}}{{{x^2} + {y^4}}} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174190)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function of two variables should be continuos, that is $\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = f(a,b)$  independent on how you approach $a,b$. You could think of this like that you are drawing a circle around the point $(a,b)$ and independent from which point on the circle that you start from "walking" to the point $(a,b)$ you should "end" at the same value.

So if we choose to start from the point $(x,x^2)$ we should end up at the value $0$ IF is continouis.

$$
f(x,x^2) = \frac{x^4}{x^4 + x^4} = \frac{1}{2} \not = 0, \ x \not = 0
$$

According to your second question, remember from early mathematics when you first learned about limits. I think it went something like this.

Lets say you have a one-dimension function $f(x)$ and you wanted to calculate the limit when $x \to a$, the first thing you would do is try to calculate $f(a)$. It $f(a)$ was definied, then you would simply say that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$. If $f(a)$ was not definied, then you would have to do some "tricks".

In this new case one simply sees that 
$$
f(0,0) = \frac{0}{1} = 0
$$
So this is no "dangerous" case, so we conlcude that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = f(0,0)$

Comment: What about the function $$g(x,y) = \left\{ \matrix{
  0,x = y = 0 \hfill \cr 
  {{{x^2}y} \over {{x^4} + {y^2} + 1}},otherwise \hfill \cr}  \right\}$$
How do I know if that is continuous at x=y=0? With this problem and a few others, I've had a substitution to make which makes it easy now that you've shown me how to solve this type of problem.

Comment: I think the best is that you make a new question (according to the rules) or that you add the above to this question using edit. Then I will be happy to answer. @Ahmed

Comment: Oh, ok. I am very sorry! I will add it to the question now.

Comment: For some reason, the edit didn't work before. I am not sure what I did wrong but I have now included it in the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I have editet @Ahmed