# Multivariable limit $\frac{(2x^2)y}{x^4+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm resolving the limit of $\frac{(2x^2).y}{x^4+y^2}$  when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

We didn't study any special theorem, we did only approach.

I tried first the  changes $y=x^2$ and $y=0$.

In $f(x,x^2)$, operating I get that the $\lim =\frac{2x^4}{2x^4}=1$
So then I test the $f(x,0)$
operating I get $\frac{2x^2.0}{x^4+0}$, that is still $0/0$,but has a zero on the numerator, that is always enough to claim that the limit of $f(x,0)$ is $0$?
Assuming that the limit $f(x,x^2)$=1 $f(x,0)$=0 so the limit don't exist.

Is right the procedure? Any way to do it easy? is right the assumption of the 0 on the numerator that the limit will be cero?
Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93886/computing-a-multivariable-limit