# To discuss continuity of $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ at origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To discuss continuity of  $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{for } (x,y)=(0,0) \\                                  \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}& \text{for }(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}.\end{cases}$$

I converted to polars and my limit goes to 0. So i think it is continuous.I am not sure though

Thanks

Comment: Compute $f(y^2,y)$ for $y\not =0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93886/321264

Answer (score 3):

Consider the parametrization $\Gamma_1(t): (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x & = t^2\\
y & = t
\end{split}
\end{equation}
the function is
$$f(t^2,t) = \dfrac{t^2 t^2}{(t^2)^2 + t^4} = \frac{1}{2}$$
whose limit is $0.5$ when $t \to 0$. It is easy to find another parametrization $\Gamma_2(s)$ whose limit is $0$ when $s \to 0$. Therefore the function is not continuous.