# Prove or disprove each of the follow function has limits $x \to a$ by the definition $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove or disprove each of the follow function has limits $x \to a$ by the definition

$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}$

Given $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = \epsilon$, then $||(x, y) - (0, 0)|| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and so $\|(x, y) - (0,0)\| < \delta$ implies that

$$\left| \frac{xy^2}{x^2-y^2} - 0\right| = \frac{|xy^2|}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \cdot (x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta = \epsilon$$

Therefore the limit does exist.

Is this right?

Comment: Yeah, it looks correct.

Comment: An older post about the same limit: [Computing A Multivariable Limit: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93886) (Several related posts are [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/93886).) And you can probably find a few more [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7B(x%2C%20y)%20%5Cto%20(0%2C%200)%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bxy%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.
$$\left|{xy^2\over x^2 + y^2 }\right| = |x| {y^2\over x^2 + y^2 } \le |x|. $$